# json_encode children items?

Tags: php, json

How can I use php json_encode to produce the following from an array?

```
{"issue":{"project_id":"Test Project","subject":"Test Issue"}}
```

I've been trying for the last 40 mins but I can't get it working for the life of me.
The best I can do is:

```
$arr = array ("project_id"=>"Baas","subject"=>"Test Issue");
echo json_encode($arr); // {"project_id":"Baas","subject":"Test Issue"}
```

The problem is making "issue" parent. Any hint on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what json_encode makes of it, but shouldn't `array("issue" => array ("project_id"=>"Baas","subject"=>"Test Issue");` work#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you want is essentially an associative array nested in another associative array. So, create that data structure, then encode it.

```
$child_arr = array("project_id" => "Baas", "subject" => "Test Issue");
$parent_arr = array("issue" => $child_arr);
echo json_encode($parent_arr);
```

Or, if we're in a one-liner mood today:

```
$arr = array("issue" => array("project_id" => "Baas", "subject" => "Test Issue"));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array ("issue" => array("project_id"=>"Baas","subject"=>"Test Issue"));
```